# How can I send a request parameter from a router? Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I don't know how to send a request parameter in a function into a Express router, i try with "req.body.email" but don't work, I am currently learning, so I would appreciate your help! :)

Error:

```
ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\Documents\Programming\Web\Project\api\src\routes\auth.route.js:17:27)

Line error: condition: {name: request.body.email}
```

auth.router:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const controller = require('../controllers/auth.controller')
const userExist = require('../middlewares/userExist')

router.post('/register', [userExist({
        condition: {name: request.body.email},
        existRequired: false,
        verifiedRequired: false,
        message: "Email already exist."
    })],
    controller.register
)
```

userExist:

```
const User = require('../models/user.model')

const userExist = async ({condition, existRequired, verifiedRequired, message}) => {
    return async (req = request, res = response, next) => {

        const user = await new User({condition}).find()

        if(existRequired && !user) return res.status(400).json({error: message})

        if(verifiedRequired && !user.verified) return res.status(404).json({error: message})

        next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro Once you called `done() or next()` Then next middleware or function is still followed by `(req,res){}`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return async (req = request, res = response, next) => {
```

to this:

```
return async (req, res, next) => {
```

There are no default values named `request` or `response` for those arguments.  Those arguments are passed by Express when it calls this middleware.  You do not and should not try to assign a default value for them.